# Facebook interactive Open Graph Stories

Tags: facebook, facebook-opengraph

Lately I'm starting to see interactive open graph stories. Not just links or images, but bar charts which you can hover and give you certain information.
An example (print screen) [here](http://s0.uploads.im/xkJNz.png).

Does anyone know wheter or not this feature is accessible for anyone? Or does Runkeeper has some kind of privilege? And IF it's possible, how? Couldn't find anything in the docs...

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Yes It's accessible for anyone. After create your app on facebook you need to by a SSL Certificate but first start with non public app. Facebook needs a secure url to publish your app. Once you have your APP you need to setting up your Open Graph. In this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=P422jZg50X4) you will learn how to publish on facebook any activity.

Visit this documentacion: [Open Graph](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api)